# CheckBox is not clickable because another element <label> obscures it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I try to select checkbox via firefox webdriver, but always get error like :

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element  is not clickable at point (482,548) because another element  obscures it

I tried several suggestions for a solution like maximizing the page, locating the checkbox element and using Actions, but none of them helped. I think the problem is about the label near the checkbox. Selenium tries to locate the center of the text I think and at that point, there exists a link to a modal window. 
[image: This is the HTML code where the regarding checkbox is defined]

[image: This is the appearance of the checkbox which is not clickable by Selenium]

A sample code is below:

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("aydinlatma"));     
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element );
    element.click();

    /*Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
    */
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to click while the page and this exact checkbox are loading. Try to implement wait mechanism for this element, smth like that:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(<locator>);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, i tried it but this time it throws another exception: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" id="aydinlatma" name="aydinlatma" value="1" required=""> is not clickable at point (477, 497). Other element would receive the click: <label>...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when locating element by its xpath instead of its name.

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[5]/div/label/i"));     
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element );
    element.click();
```